# Unit tests failing with 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0'

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

I've searched and found similar questions but the given answers don't work for me.

This is specific to .NET Core.  I'm writing unit tests with Xunit and Moq and I'm getting the error of

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

My Test project's project.json file looks like the following:

```
{
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "buildOptions": {
      "debugType": "portable"
   },
   "dependencies": {
      "xunit": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
      "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
      "My.App.DataAccess": "1.0.0",
      "My.App.Domain": "1.0.0",
      "My.App.Services": "1.0.0",
      "My.App.WebApi": "1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost": "1.1.0",
      "Moq": "4.5.30"
   },
   "testRunner": "xunit",

   "frameworks": {
      "net462": {}
   }
}
```

Only the unit tests are failing.  The main application works just fine.  I've tried manually forcing System.Net into the project.json but it insists on installing 4.3.0.  I'm not sure where it's thinking it needs 4.1.1.0.

EDIT: I noticed that if I copy System.Net.Http.dll from the WebApi project bin to the Test project bin everything works fine.  Now, the test project itself does not use anything from the System.Net.Http namespace -- only the method being tested in the WebApi project references it.

Should the Test project have the System.Net.Http.dll copied to it's bin folder as well?  If so, why is this not occurring during the build process?

Comment: Do you get any warnings during package restore?

Comment: Nope.  Everything seems hunky-dory.

Comment: you could check assembly binding log as described in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net) to figure out why your app need this specific version

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to this: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9846

I recommend updating to VS 2017 and do a binding redirect for the `System.Net.Http` assembly.

Comment: How do we do a binding redirect in the new csproj structure? I'm not getting any hits for it on internet searches.